# I need to implement mutliple options but only one correct answer in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to create database using mysql .

The problem that i am getting is how to keep the options for the a question in a table as the number of options can change as questions changes.

Example:- One question can have 4 options and other question can have 7 options but only one correct option.

Comment: and where is the problem? one table for questions, one for answers with an id or something to link to the question and you're done!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One table for Questions.

Since one question can have many answers, One table for answers, and primary key of questions table will come as a foreign key in answers table, it will make this a `one to many relationship`.

> Questions table
>
> id question
>
> Answers table
>
> id, question_id, answer, is_correct_answer

Comment: +1 This also allows for the possibillity of multiple correct answers to a single question.